# How to get the url response values in Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I almost dare to ask, but how can i get the response data of a URL?
I just can't remember anymore.

My scenario: I'm using the twitter API to get the profile picture of an user. That API URL returns the JPEG location.
So if I actually write this HTML in my views:

```
<img src="https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger"/>
```

The browser auto uses the response JPEG for the SRC property. Like this:

[image]

Now is my question very simple: how can I get that .jpg location in C# to put in my database?

Comment: why do you dare :) ..its pretty gud question!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.

I think you can use `WebClient.DownloadData` in c# to call that url. Once you download the file, you can then place it in the database.

```
byte[] response = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url);
```

[Download a file over HTTP into a byte array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278986/download-a-file-over-http-into-a-byte-array-in-c)

EDIT: THIS IS WORKING FOR ME

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);

Console.Read( );
```

from [A way to figure out redirection URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382646/a-way-to-figure-out-redirection-url)

EDIT: THIS IS ANOTHER METHOD I THINK...using show.json from [Read the absolute redirected SRC attribute URL for an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421729/read-the-absolute-redirected-src-attribute-url-for-an-image)

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterapi

Comment: Thx for your reply. But the byte data isn't really necessary.
By calling the API url twitter gives back the location of the profilepicture. You can test it if you post the url 'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger' in your browser.
I would like to store the jpg location returned by the Twitter API

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it using HttpClient:

```
public class UriFetcher
{
    public Uri Get(string apiUri)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(apiUri).Result;
            return httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri;
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class UriFetcherTester
{
    [Test]
    public void Get()
    {
        var uriFetcher = new UriFetcher();
        var fetchedUri = uriFetcher.Get("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger");
        Console.WriteLine(fetchedUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer; +1 for simple example and a test too :-)

Comment: Thx for your answer as well, but I feel more comfortable with Timmerz code. Was usfull, so upvote.

Comment: Note: you need to be using System.Net.Http - .net framework 4.5 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes (via `using System.Net`)to achieve this;

```
  HttpWebRequest webRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger") as HttpWebRequest;

  webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

  HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

  string url = response.ResponseUri.OriginalString;
```

url now contains the string `"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1438634086/avatar_bigger.png"`